# Difference between response.statusCode and response.status

Tags: javascript

I was writing a function that shows dialogwindow on the button click:here the piece of code related to status and statusCode.

```
     if(response.status>300){
                  jQuery("#myModal").modal("show");
                }else{
    vm.someFunction();
                }


  // when I run the code above I got result working, however when I wrote //the following:



  if(response.statusCode>300){
                   jQuery("#myModal").modal("show");
                }else{
    vm.someFunction();
                }

// it does not work although my statusCode was 500;
```

So, my question is: what is the difference between status and statusCode and when I should use some of them.?

Comment: The first `if` statement uses `response.status` while the second one uses `response.statusCode` - make sure they both exist in the first place.

Comment: What kind of object is `response`? It seems the modal dialog and `someFunction` have nothing to do with your question. It would be more useful to include where you get that object from.

Comment: Hi, vm1.positionCreate = function(lot){

        factoryLots.createPosition(lot).then(function (response) {
            if(response.status>300){
              // jQuery("#myModal").modal("show");
                BootstrapDialog.alert("заполните поля правильно")
            }else{
vm1.fillTicketFunction();
            }
        });
    }   Here is my whole function,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Client-side (in the browser), and using `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch`, the correct property to use is called [`response.status`](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-status-attribute)

Server-side, in Node.js, using `http.ClientRequest` (when dealing with the response of an HTTP request that you made using Node.js), the correct property to use is called [`response.statusCode`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_statuscode)

Also server-side, in Node.js, using `http.ServerResponse` (to *set* a status code for a particular response), the correct property to use is also called [`response.statusCode`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_statuscode)

Comment: thanks for your answer, now it is clear to me @robertklep

Comment: While writing an API testcase using Jest, I am using response.status to verify the status of a server I am trying to test. I am assuming that would be the correct way because my test script is basically a client. Just wondering if there was a reason to do otherwise?

Comment: @Souparno I haven't used Jest in a while, but if `response.status` works (in that it reflects the correct status for the things you're testing), I don't see a reason to use something else.